# Using php to embed videos

Tags: php, video, embed

I'm trying to create a variable from a csv and display it. The value is an embedded YouTube video.

Ignore the csv part for now.

When I use this code the video can't be found. If I just use the embed code in html it works as expected, I got it right from YouTube. The class is fine when I use the html directly, and removing the class didn't fix the problem on this page. What do I need to do to use a php variable to display video embed?

```
<?php

//prints the 4th row, second column.
$test ="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/a57OYN-gTVo";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
</head>

<body>

<h1>basketball</h1>
<h2>Ball</h2>
<br>

<div class="videoSpot">
<h2></h2>
<iframe width="500" height="360" src="<? echo $test; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>       </iframe></div>

<div class="videoSpot">
<h2></h2>
<iframe width="500" height="360" src="<? echo $test; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>    </iframe></div>

<div class="videoSpot">
<h2></h2>
<iframe width="500" height="360" src='<? echo $test; ?>' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check YouTube on how you're supposed to use their links. It's just a little bit of boilerplate. No actual PHP code is required.

Comment: I'd be using the php to randomly display videos from data in a csv. Not sure how else I could do that but I'm pretty new and open to new ideas.

Comment: You need PHP to fill in the boilerplate, but PHP doesn't do any of the stuff required to show a video, that's all YouTube.

Comment: Right but the format of the video embed doesn't work when I reference it with a php variable. Which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Look at the output HTML. Does it look like you expect?

Comment: <iframe width="500" height="360" src="&lt;?php echo $test; ?&gt;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

Comment: Shouldn't the php part appear as html?

Comment: It should. Your php code isn't getting parsed/executed. Make sure the file extension is `.php` and that php is configured properly.